# Application sometimes crashes when opening a dialog on only one machine

Tags: c#, .net, windows-xp

so this is kind of a weird error. On one machine from one of our customers (Windows XP SP3) our program crashes when trying to open a filter dialog via ShowDialog().

What happens: The user works as expected he/she does nothing unnormal or wrong and everything he/she does is/was tested on several machines (ranging from Win XP 32 bit to Win 7 64 bit).

Now, after some time he/she want's to use the filter dialog (which he/she did at that point like a dozen times) and the application crashes. You get that wonderful "$applicationname caused a problem and has to be terminated" message from Windows XP, beneath it you can see the filter dialog, partially build (meaning: you can see the window, a scroll bar and transparent 'holes' where the text controls/labels should be.

In the Windows eventviewer you can see an entry like this

> Event ID: 1000
> Source: .NET Runtime 4.0 Error Re *(maybe something stands behind this and it says 'Reporting'?!)*
>
> Faulting application $applicationname.exe, version $versionnumber,
> stamp $someRandomNumbers, faulting module ntdll.dll, version
> 5.1.2600.6055, stamp 4d00f27b, debug?0, fault address 0x00446da

Now, what weirds me out: The position where the dialog is opened via ShowDialog, is embedded in 2(!) try...catch blocks. How is it possible for the application to crash? There aren't even logfileentries (something that is done in EVERY catch block we've in that program and it's always the first thing we do) about this crash.

I already uninstalled the application and .NET 4 from that machine, rebooted installed everything again, installed Windows Updates and rebooted again. Same result.

*edit
just noticed something: When I close the message from microsoft, an additional entry in the eventviewer is created:

> The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception *I guess that's the meaning in english, since the original message is in another language I had to translate*
>
> Exceptioncode: c015000f, address 7c9546DA *address is always the same*

Comment: Just googling ".net c015000f" gives me a couple of hotfixes and blogentries to look at.. I suggest you take a look at those..

Comment: This exception is caused by a programming bug, incorrect use of the De/ActivateActCtx winapi functions.  It is associated with displaying a dialog since those functions are often used to enable visual styles.  That's about all that can be guessed from the provided info.

Comment: @riffnl hmm, took a quick look (I used slightly different search terms but the results where basically the same), those are nearly all related to running a 32bit application on a 64bit Windows (WoW) which is not happening here.

Comment: @Hans sounds interesting. One of my colleagues thought that maybe insufficient video RAM was responsible for this so we deactivated visual styles, after that the amount of errors was reduced and the error appeared when closing the filter dialog, which (I guess) connects quite nicely to your piece of information

Comment: [Profanity is not welcome here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22233/142838).

Comment: There could very well be some optional updates available from Windows Update that target specific issues like this.

Comment: @meagar how is that a profanity?! I wasn't insulting anyone. It was merely a note about how frustrating the issue at hand was. And why are you pulling a one year old question back up about this?!

Answer (score 0):

As @Hans said, it's caused by incorrect use of the De/ActivateActCtx winapi functions.

I met the same problem when I write a VB App. using my ActiveX Contrl(MFC). I place a dialog variant in the control class definition. 
Like below:

```
CMyDlg dlg;
```

So when does the dialog initilized is not in my control. And that made the same issue as you. When the control should be displayed, the error appears.